# Code Not Completing Before Next Method Is Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, completionhandler

In my iOS app, I am using the forecast.io API to get a weather forecast for 3 specific days.  Once I get the array from all 3, I want to create an NSMutableArray and add all of those objects to it. The problem I am getting is that it is trying to create the NSMutableArray before the forecast data is retrieved.  Here is what I have so far:

```
typedef void(^myCompletion)(BOOL);
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self myMethod:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished){
            NSMutableArray *allOfIt = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.weatherSaturday, self.weatherSunday, self.weatherMonday, nil];
            NSLog(@"%@", allOfIt);
        }
    }];

}
-(void) myMethod:(myCompletion) compblock{
    //do stuff
    ForecastKit *forecast = [[ForecastKit alloc] initWithAPIKey:@"MY-API-KEY"];
    // Request the forecast for a location at a specified time
    [forecast getDailyForcastForLatitude:37.438905 longitude:-106.886051 time:1467475200 success:^(NSArray *saturday) {

    //    NSLog(@"%@", saturday);
        self.weatherSaturday = saturday;


    } failure:^(NSError *error){

        NSLog(@"Daily w/ time %@", error.description);

    }];

    [forecast getDailyForcastForLatitude:37.438905 longitude:-106.886051 time:1467561600 success:^(NSArray *sunday) {

        //  NSLog(@"%@", sunday);
        self.weatherSunday = sunday;

    } failure:^(NSError *error){

        NSLog(@"Daily w/ time %@", error.description);

    }];

    [forecast getDailyForcastForLatitude:37.438905 longitude:-106.886051 time:1467648000 success:^(NSArray *monday) {

        // NSLog(@"%@", monday);
        self.weatherMonday = monday;

    } failure:^(NSError *error){

        NSLog(@"Daily w/ time %@", error.description);

    }];

    compblock(YES);
}
```

When the code is ran, it fires the NSLog for allOfIt, which shows as null, before it gets any of the forecast data.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem I am getting is that it is trying to create the NSMutableArray before the forecast data is retrieved

Yup, exactly. The problem is simply that you don't understand what "asynchronous" means. *Networking takes time*, and it all happens in the background. Meanwhile, your main code *does not pause*; it is all executed instantly.

Things, therefore, do not happen in the order in which your code is written. All three `getDailyForcastForLatitude` calls fire off immediately and the whole method ends. Then, slowly, one by one, in no particular order, the server calls back and the three completion handlers (the stuff in curly braces) are called.

If you want the completion handlers to be called in order, you need each `getDailyForcastForLatitude` call to be made *in the completion handler* of the `getDailyForcastForLatitude` call that precedes it. Or, write your code in such a way that it doesn't matter when and in what order the completion handlers come back to you.

Comment: The latter will usually be a lot faster since all three messages go to the server and come back simultaneously.